# MySQL select user's place

Tags: mysql, rating

I have a table users:

```
id  |   rating
1       4
2       -1
3       12
4       0
5       2
6       0
```

How I can select user's place ordering by rating where `id = N` and that users with similar rating have the same place in the top?

**UPD:** I want to output:

If `userid = 1`, his `rank is 2`, if `userid = 2`, his `rank is 5`, if `userid = 3`, `rank is 1`, ...
But if `userid = 4` or `6` their `rank are 4` because rates are similar.

Comment: can you show here what is ur expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to find the rating for asll user_id's`:

```
SELECT id,
       IF(rating <> @var_rating_prev, (@var_rank:= @var_rank + 1), @var_rank) AS rank,
       (@var_rating_prev := rating) AS rating
FROM table_name a,(SELECT @var_rank := 0, @var_rating_prev := 0) r
ORDER BY rating DESC;
```

## Example @ [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3fdf/7)

If you don't want to change the order of records in output then try this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.rank
FROM test_table a
     INNER JOIN (
            SELECT id,
                   IF(rating <> @var_rating_prev, (@var_rank:= @var_rank + 1), @var_rank) AS rank,
                   (@var_rating_prev := rating) AS rating
            FROM test_table a,(SELECT @var_rank := 0, @var_rating_prev := 0) r
            ORDER BY rating DESC
        ) b
         ON a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Comment: OP wants for a given user id find whats his rank in rating system

Comment: @Omesh, I found some problems. I want to get rank for one user. WHERE id = 10 ORDER BY rating DESC;
It works, but if id = 2 rank is 0. I do not understand

Comment: See sqlfiddle demo, it's working. If you have a particular case where it's not working, then can you update that fiddle and provide link here?

Comment: That's because you have zero and null values in your database. Try initializing `@rank` counter to `NULL` see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3fdf/15

Comment: With your last query I get rank is 1 for any IDs. Try change the id in youe query. Rank already is 1

Comment: In that case you will have to use second query with extra where clause for id. See  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3fdf/17

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 `rank`
FROM table_name
WHERE rating > (SELECT rating
                FROM table_name
                WHERE id = N)
```